# In the polynomial ring $\mathbb Z_3[x]$, the ideal generated by $x^6+1$ is a prime ideal.

Tags: ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

> In the polynomial ring $\mathbb Z_3[x]$, the ideal generated by $x^6+1$ is a prime ideal.

My attempt:

**Theorem:** Let $F$ be a field and $f(x)\in F[x]$. The ideal is $\langle f(x) \rangle$ is maximal iff $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F$.

Here $Z_3$ is a field, and the ideal generated by $x^6+1$ is maximal since $x^6+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_3$.  So, $\langle x^6+1 \rangle$ is maximal and hence prime as every maximal ideal is prime ideal.
Hence,  the ideal generated by $x^6+1$ is a prime ideal.

**Method 2:**

**Theorem:**$F[x]$ is a PID iff $F$ is a field.

**Theorem:** Let $R$ be a PID. For an non-zero ideal $I$ such that $I \neq R$, then $I$ is prime ideal iff $I$ is maximal ideal.
Using the above proof again, $I=\langle x^6+1 \rangle$ is maximal and hence prime.

But my answer key says this is false, am I doing something wrong here? Please try to explicitly point out where I am wrong and also what would be the correct approach. Thanks !

Comment: Over the field of three elements: $x^6+1=(x^2+1)^3$.

Comment: Okay. This would imply it being not prime ideal, but where have I gone wrong, could you help me with that?

Comment: You said $x^6+1$ is irreducible..

Comment: Even over $\Bbb Z$, $x^6+1=(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)$ is reducible.

Comment: but for $x=0,1,2$, i dont get $x^6+1=0$, this is how we check irreducibility right?

Comment: $(x^6+1) = (x^2+1) ( x^4-x^2+1) $ !!!

Comment: That does not suggest irreducibility.

Comment: No, that is **not** how you check irreducibility. That is how you check it has no linear factors. @NAVI-s1mpleo

Comment: It's only a convenient method to use in simple and particular cases.

Comment: Thanks @AnginaSeng and Yourong for the help. I understand my mistake now. (sorry I am unable to tag more than 1 person)

Answer (score 2):

We know ideal $I$ is prime iff $\frac{R}{I}$ is integral domain

Here $I= <x^6+1> $

We have.
$a= (x^2+1)\neq0 $ and$b=(x^4-x^2+1) \neq 0$ in $\frac{Z_3[x]}{<x^6+1>}$

But $ab =(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1) =0$

$\implies \frac{Z_3[x]}{<x^6+1>}$ is not an integral domain

$\implies  <x^6+1> $is not prime

Comment: Another easy way to factor it is that by the [Freshman dream theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream#:~:text=The%20freshman's%20dream%20is%20a,assuming%20powers%20distribute%20over%20sums.), $x^6+1=(x^2+1)^3$.  Oh, ooop i see in the comments above it was covered as well..